# How can I Translate or run a VBscript function inside a ps1 file?

Tags: c#, powershell, vbscript

Hi I've got a old VBscript that I've got a implemented function inside.

this function contain a object that can execute and stop a program called QTP as well as other more advanced parts up against this program.

as I've not been able to find any way to do this in Powershell I figured why not just reuse that one function from my old VBscript file. well as it turns out this is slightly more complicated than what I thought.

as I can't use MSScriptControl.ScriptControl to access my VBscript I thought well maybe I can find something in .net preferable C# 
but the few ways I found execute the entire script and not just that one function. for example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"cscript //B //Nologo c:\yourfile.vbs");
```

so I'm asking here now How can I either execute that one function from my Powershell file or translate it to Powershell here is the functions code:

```
Public Sub ExecuteTest(ByVal TestPath , ByVal TestName)
 Dim qtApp 'As QuickTest.Application ' Declare the Application object variable
 Dim qtTest 'As QuickTest.Test ' Declare a Test object variable
 Dim qtResultsOpt 'As QuickTest.RunResultsOptions ' Declare a Run Results Options object variable
 strLog = "Start " & TestName
 WriteLogToFile(strLog)
 Set qtApp = CreateObject("QuickTest.Application") ' Create the Application object
 qtApp.Launch ' Start QuickTest
 qtApp.Visible = False ' Make the QuickTest application invisible
 qtApp.Visible = True ' Make the QuickTest application visible

 ' Set QuickTest run options: 
 ' Always--Captures images for all steps in the run. 
 ' OnError--Captures images only for failed steps. 
 ' OnWarning--Captures images only for steps that return a failed or warning status. 
 ' Never--Never captures images. 

   qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "Always"
 ' qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnError"
 ' qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnWarning"
 ' qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "Never"


 qtApp.Options.Run.RunMode = "Fast"
 qtApp.Options.Run.ViewResults = False

 'This will Open a script
 ' Wscript.Echo  TestPath
  qtApp.Open TestPath , False ' Open the test in edit mode
 ' qtApp.Open TestPath , True ' Open the test in read-only mode

 ' set run settings for the test

 Set qtTest = qtApp.Test

 ' qtTest.Settings.Run.IterationMode = "rngIterations" ' Run only iterations 2 to 4
 ' qtTest.Settings.Run.StartIteration = 1
 ' qtTest.Settings.Run.EndIteration = 1
 ' qtTest.Settings.Run.OnError = "NextStep" ' Instruct QuickTest to perform next step when error occurs

 'For Viewing Results
 Set qtResultsOpt = CreateObject("QuickTest.RunResultsOptions") ' Create the Run Results Options object

 ' WScript.Echo  letter & testresult & TestName & "\Result_"  & GetDateTimeStr

 qtResultsOpt.ResultsLocation = letter & testresult & TestName & "\Result_"  & GetDateTimeStr ' Set the results location
 qtTest.Run qtResultsOpt ' Run the test

 While qtTest.IsRunning
   'Wait For Test To Finish
 Wend

 strLog = "Slut " & TestName  &  qtTest.LastRunResults.Status 

 ' qtApp.Options.Run.ViewResults = True
 WriteLogToFile(strLog)


 'Close QTP
 qtTest.Close() ' Close the test

 'Set the options to nothing
 Set qtResultsOpt = Nothing ' Release the Run Results Options object
 Set qtTest = Nothing ' Release the Test object
 Set qtApp = Nothing ' Release the Application object

End Sub
```

Thanks for the help I've used what I got from David Martin below here and found the solutions to the problem with the invisible methods and properties. here is the working method:

```
  function ExecuteTest($TestPath,$letter,$testresult,$TestName)
{
    #Update-TypeData -Prepend .\ComObject.Types.ps1xml
    #param($TestPath=[string],$TestName=[string])

    $qtApp = New-Object -comobject QuickTest.Application -strict

    $strLog = "Start $TestName" 
    WriteLogToFile($strLog)
    # Start QuickTest
    [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember(“Launch”,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$qtApp,$null,$null,$null,$null)

    Start-Sleep -Seconds 10
    $obj = New-Object System.Object
    # Make the QuickTest application invisible
    $obj = $False
    #Make the QuickTest application visible
    $obj = $True
    $myArray = @($nul)
    $myArray[0] =$obj
    #Wait for the aplication to be initialized 

    #Apply the Visibility Variable to the QuickTest application
    [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("Visible",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::SetProperty,$null,$qtApp,$myArray)

    #Make the QuickTest application visible
    #$qtApp.Visible = $True 



    # Set QuickTest run options: 
    # Always--Captures images for all steps in the run. 
    # OnError--Captures images only for failed steps. 
    # OnWarning--Captures images only for steps that return a failed or warning status. 
    # Never--Never captures images. 

    $qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "Always"
    # $qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnError"
    # $qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnWarning"
    # $qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "Never"
    $obj = "Fast"
    $myArray[0] =$obj
    [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("RunMode",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::SetProperty,$null,$qtApp.Options.Run,$myArray)

    #$qtApp.Options.Run.RunMode = "Fast"

    #$qtApp.Options.Run.ViewResults = $False
    $obj = $False
    $myArray[0] =$obj
    [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember("ViewResults",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::SetProperty,$null,$qtApp.Options.Run,$myArray)

    #This will Open a script
    # Wscript.Echo  TestPath
    $obj = $False
    $myArray[0] = $TestPath
    $myArray += $obj
    #Invoke-Method - inputobject $qtApp -MethodName Open -MethodParameters $myArray -Static
    $qtApp.GetType().InvokeMember(“Open”,#Method Name
        [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,#BindingFlag
        $null,#Binder
        $qtApp,#Target
        ($TestPath),#Args
        $null,#Modifiers
        $null,#culture
        $null) #[string[]]("TestPath"))#namedParameters
  # [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember(“Open”,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$qtApp,([Object[]]$myArray),$null,$null,$null)
    #$qtApp.Open #$TestPath, $False #' Open the test in edit mode
    # $qtApp.Open $TestPath , $True #' Open the test in read-only mode
    # set run settings for the test
    $qtTest = $qtApp.GetType().InvokeMember("Test",[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::GetProperty,$null,$qtApp,$null)

    # $qtTest.Settings.Run.IterationMode = "rngIterations" ' Run only iterations 2 to 4
    # $qtTest.Settings.Run.StartIteration = 1
    # $qtTest.Settings.Run.EndIteration = 1
    # $qtTest.Settings.Run.OnError = "NextStep" ' Instruct QuickTest to perform next step when error occurs

    # WScript.Echo  letter & testresult & TestName & "\Result_"  & GetDateTimeStr

    # The following variables have not been defined
    #letter
    #testresult
    # This function doesn't exist
    #GetDateTimeStr
    $qtResultsOpt = New-Object -comobject QuickTest.RunResultsOptions -strict
    #$qtResultsOpt = FileSystemObject QuickTest.RunResultsOptions
    $ParentPath = $letter + $testresult + $TestName 
    $ChildPath = "\Result_" + $("{0:yyyymmddTHHMMss}" -f $(get-date))
    $ResultOptArgs = join-path -path $ParentPath -childpath  $ChildPath
    [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember(“ResultsLocation”,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::SetProperty,$null,$qtResultsOpt,$ResultOptArgs)
    #$qtResultsOpt.GetType().InvokeMember(“ResultsLocation”,#Method Name
     #   [System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,#BindingFlag
      #  $null,#Binder
       # $qtResultsOpt,#Target
        #($ResultOptArgs),#Args
       # $null,#Modifiers
        #$null,#culture
       # $null) #[string[]]("TestPath"))#namedParameters


    # Run the test
    $qtTest.GetType().InvokeMember(“Run”,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$qtTest,($qtResultsOpt),$null,$null,$null)
    #$qtTest.Run # $qtResultsOpt 


    do
    {
        Start-Sleep -m 100
    }
    while($qtTest.IsRunning)

    $strLog = "Slut $TestName $(qtTest.LastRunResults.Status)"

    # qtApp.Options.Run.ViewResults = True
    WriteLogToFile($strLog)


    #Close QTP
    #$qtTest.Close() 
    [System.__ComObject].InvokeMember(“Close”,[System.Reflection.BindingFlags]::InvokeMethod,$null,$qtTest,$null,$null,$null,$null)
    #Set the options to nothing
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($qtResultsOpt)
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($qtTest)
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($qtApp)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a quick stab at translating this for you, I don't have QuickTest so I can't test this for you.

```
function WriteLogToFile
{
    param ($message)
    write-host message
}

function ExecuteTest
{
    param
    (
        $TestPath,
        $TestName
    )

    $qtApp = New-Object -comobject QuickTest.Application -strict
    $qtTest = New-Object -comobject QuickTest.Test -strict
    $qtResultsOpt = New-Object -comobject QuickTest.RunResultsOptions

    $strLog = "Start $TestName" 
    WriteLogToFile($strLog)

    # Start QuickTest
    $qtApp.Launch 

    # Make the QuickTest application invisible
    $qtApp.Visible = $false 

    #Make the QuickTest application visible
    $qtApp.Visible = True 


    # Set QuickTest run options: 
    # Always--Captures images for all steps in the run. 
    # OnError--Captures images only for failed steps. 
    # OnWarning--Captures images only for steps that return a failed or warning status. 
    # Never--Never captures images. 

    $qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "Always"
    # $qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnError"
    # $qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "OnWarning"
    # $qtApp.Options.Run.ImageCaptureForTestResults = "Never"

    qtApp.Options.Run.RunMode = "Fast"
    qtApp.Options.Run.ViewResults = False

    #This will Open a script
    write-host "TestPath: [$TestPath]"
    $qtApp.Open $TestPath , $false ' Open the test in edit mode
    # $qtApp.Open TestPath , True ' Open the test in read-only mode

    # set run settings for the test
    $qtTest = $qtApp.Test

    # $qtTest.Settings.Run.IterationMode = "rngIterations" ' Run only iterations 2 to 4
    # $qtTest.Settings.Run.StartIteration = 1
    # $qtTest.Settings.Run.EndIteration = 1
    # $qtTest.Settings.Run.OnError = "NextStep" ' Instruct QuickTest to perform next step when error occurs

    # WScript.Echo  letter & testresult & TestName & "\Result_"  & GetDateTimeStr

    # The following variables have not been defined
    #letter
    #testresult
    # This function doesn't exist
    #GetDateTimeStr

    $qtResultsOpt.ResultsLocation = join-path -path "c:\results" -childpath $("{0:yyyymmddTHHMMss}" -f $(get-date))

    # Run the test
    $qtTest.Run qtResultsOpt 


    do
        Start-Sleep -m 100
    while($qtTest.IsRunning)

    $strLog = "Slut $TestName $(qtTest.LastRunResults.Status)"

    # qtApp.Options.Run.ViewResults = True
    WriteLogToFile($strLog)


    #Close QTP
    $qtTest.Close() 

    #Set the options to nothing
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($qtResultsOpt)
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($qtTest)
    [System.Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($qtApp)
}
```

Comment: You have gotten a much better result in translateing it than I did, however when trying to run it it complains about this line 

$qtApp.Open $TestPath , $false ' Open the test in edit mode

so I changed it to this.
$qtApp.Open $TestPath , $false # Open the test in edit mode

However the problem seems to be the TestPath variable it doesn't seem like it knows where it comes from.

here is the error text it is giving me:

Unexpected token 'TestPath' in expression or statement.
At [Location/myPowershellscript].ps1:83 char:26

Comment: Insert the following before line 83: write-host "TestPath: [$TestPath]"

Comment: This should tell you what the value of the variable is set to.

Comment: it will not even let me execute the test so looking at the variables content is not possible.

when I comment out the part behind $qtApp.Open it does not make this error. seems to me to be some sort of parameter error on the Open method. Maybe it's the wrong type of value being parsed to it. how can I ensure that it's a Clean string without any other values around the string ?

Comment: But the value of the variable should be displayed on the screen if you add the line.  (I've updated the sample above).

Comment: yes it's correct it should however that only happens if the powershell_ise allows the script to run in the first place this error happens before the script is running.

Comment: However I've been looking more in to this it looks like the problem is that PowerShell won't cast COM objects to their interfaces, which makes a bunch of methods invisible on some of the COM APIs

Comment: I've put yours as the correct answer because you led me to the correct answer by making a quick translation from VB to Powershell I saw how I could use your translation together with some knowledge about invisible methods and properties. you can see the complete solution in my post above. Thank you Very much!